# How can I perform high-level database merging for WordPress within continues delivery?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, git, branching-and-merging

I've a bit of a problem. I'm currently trying to realize a WordPress development process regarding to one of my old question / topic:

[Wordpress development process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48890019/wordpress-development-process)

So currently I've **GitLab** installed (which is a free and good solution for small projects). On GitLab I've 3 branches: `prod`, `staging`, `develop`.

Regarding to these 3 branches, I've 3 instances of WordPress running.

Everything works good (Branching, updating files and all the stuff) until I need to make a **plugin update**. The problem is, that I only want to do updates on my `develop` instance in the future. So when I do an update, I can push all updates files to git. But there is a huge problem - the database.

I've tried to do some research to find out if there is any tool to make my databases working like GIT but I can't find any Open Source Tool which seems to be good enough to handle this task. There is a plugin for this, but I don't want to use a plugin.

So I hope there is a better solution to perform a continues delivery process like this here in WordPress:

[image]

Does anyone have experience with this kind of process within WordPress? If yes, how do you handle this to be 100 % safe with developing and updating WordPress?

I'm thankful for any ideas / help / experiences I can get!

Comment: This post might be helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846659/how-can-i-put-a-database-under-git-version-control

Answer (score 3):

I have reviewed your question and the visual diagram that you have presented over here. I have also done lots of thinking on this process to build the WordPress website with the powerful development process and start doing research on google.

After some days I get to know a very good system which absolutely follows the above process by default. ***The name of the tool is roots.io***

We have used this system on our local and on the server for some of our clients and they also fill like this is an absolutely perfect and secure tool for use. It is a little bit tough and difficult to install but after installation, you will see this is absolutely game changer tool for WordPress website development.

**Best Feature:-**

- This tool installed the operating system and manage via virtual machine and create an environment as you have on the live server called 'trellis'.
- They are using WordPress boilerplate with modern development tools, easier configuration, and an improved folder structure called 'bedrock'.
- They use sage theme with SASS based platform which is very powerful.
- Even if the client can not able to install any plugin or edit the code from the theme editor, related to coding we only need to operate through the local development environment.
- It also has multiple staging environments like:-

  1. Development
  2. Staging
  3. Production

**You can review some more details from here: https://roots.io**

I hope this will help you to find your solution as I got my solution by using this.

Thank you